# What is the body part that rhymes with Dolores?

Tags: plot-explanation, seinfeld

In the *Seinfeld* episode "The Junior Mints" Jerry is going out with a girl whose name he can't remember, who tells him that it rhymes with a part of the female anatomy. Later we discover that her name is Dolores. What body part does that rhyme with?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Clitoris](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clitoris), though it only rhymes with a specific pronunciation (cli-TO-ris instead of CLI-toris). It's discussed on the episode's [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Junior_Mint) which also explains George's bizarre name suggestions (e.g. Loleola) and includes this little tidbit:

> According to the "Inside Look" from the DVD, the writers had trouble coming up with a name for Jerry's girlfriend, initially settling upon "Cloris". When filming the episode, a comedian would warm up the studio audience in between filming scenes and asked them to guess Jerry's girlfriend's name; one audience member guessed Dolores, which was deemed a better fit than their first choice. Jerry Seinfeld approved in time to add it to the script and the scene was shot with that being the character's name. Afterwards, a producer for the show was amused to overhear the audience member's husband saying "you guessed right!"

Comment: I think George didn’t suggest “Loleola”. He suggested “Celeste”, “Kest”, “Rest”, “Sest”, “Hest”, “Aretha”, “Bovary” and “Mulva”. Jerry tried “Gipple” and “Loleola” at the end of the episode.

Comment: We don't actually get confirmation that her name is Dolores.  I was thinking "Regina" and assumed that this was so obvious that they left out the confirmation in the show.

Comment: They more or less confirm it in S8:E1 where she shows back up and he keeps dropping her name into the conversation w/ her over and over.

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin Do you know what is Aretha supposed to rhyme with?

Comment: @kaqqao Urethra

Comment: @xdhmoore This is a certainty.  In one episode, Jerry and George see her coming from the other way, in front of the store-fronts.  And Jerry says, "Oh, hiii Dolores."  I believe he says it multiple times in this scene to impress upon her that he knows her name.  Doesn't he try to get her to go out with him in the same scene?